# How to only set the width for a paperclip uploaded image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, paperclip

I am uploading a large image to my model using Paperclip. I'd like to only set the width of the image and let it resize the height automatically.

```
has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :large => "900", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

In the `:medium` and `:thumb` sizes I am setting both height and width. In the `:large` I just want to set the width and let it be as high as it needs to be.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `:large => "900x"`. This should resize width to  the desired value and keep original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Width only: `:large => "900"`

Height only: `:large => "x900"`

More commands: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry